# Using InStr function to match values from an array to another

Tags: vba, excel

**Context**

I am using a code and trying to make a little change in the function from `IsInArray(custom)` to `Instr` but get a compiling error.

I am simply tring to change

```
"If IsInArray(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11).Value, vAllSheet2Values)"
```

to

```
 If InStr(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11).Value, vAllSheet2Values)
```

But it's giving a compile error. Can't I simply change the function ? If not how can I do this?

**Code**

```
            Sub remDup()
            Dim LR As Long, LRSheet2 As Long, i As Long, a As Long
            Dim vAllSheet2Values() As Variant

            LRSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
            LR = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
            a = 2

            For i = 1 To LRSheet2 
                ReDim Preserve vAllSheet2Values(i)
                vAllSheet2Values(i) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Value
            Next i

            For i = LR To 1 Step -1
                If IsInArray(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11).Value, vAllSheet2Values) Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows(a)
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Delete
                    a = a + 1
                End If
            Next i
            End Sub

            Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
                IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
            End Function
```

Comment: Look at the expected parameters for `InStr` to figure out what you're missing. One hint is that the first parameter is the `Start` index in the given string (not the string itself)

Comment: Already Tried but no success.

Comment: Your `IsInArray` function works on an array of strings. The `InStr` function works on a single `String` and cannot work on an array. You have a fundamental mismatch in parameters when you make a change as you are suggesting. If you choose to use `InStr`, you'll have to create a loop to check each array value individually.

Comment: InStr returns an integer value, The reason your getting compile error is most likely due to a mismatch. :)

Comment: Why not to use `Application.Match`?

Comment: Hello All, Appreciate all of you for insights but I am new in using VBA so if you could show me a little how that would be really nice thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Depending on the size of `LR` and `LRSheet2`, this code *could* take a while to run. This is one way of using `InStr()` to compare the cells in each column.

**I defined your sheets, defined the `Rows.Count` parts of `LR` and `LRSheet2`, and included a second `For Loop` to cycle through each item in your `vAllSheet2Values()` array.**

```
Option Explicit
Sub remDup()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet: Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    Dim LR As Long, LRSheet2 As Long, i As Long, a As Long
    Dim vAllSheet2Values() As String, sheet2Val As Variant

    LRSheet2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    LR = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
    a = 2

    For i = 1 To LRSheet2
        ReDim Preserve vAllSheet2Values(i)
        If ws2.Cells(i, 3).Value <> "" Then _
            vAllSheet2Values(i) = CStr(ws2.Cells(i, 3).Value) 'Don't add blanks
        Debug.Print ws2.Cells(i, 3).Value
    Next i

    For i = LR To 1 Step -1
        If ws1.Cells(i, 11).Value = "" Then GoTo SkipTheRest 'Skip blanks
        For Each sheet2Val In vAllSheet2Values
            If InStr(sheet2Val, CStr(ws1.Cells(i, 11).Value)) <> 0 Then
                ws1.Rows(i).Copy ws3.Rows(a)
                ws1.Rows(i).Delete
                a = a + 1
                GoTo SkipTheRest 'Match found, skip the rest
            End If
        Next sheet2Val
        'You can include the following statement if you want to catch when there
        'isn't a match on Sheet1
        'MsgBox "No match found for " & ws1.Cells(i, 11).Value, vbOKOnly, "No Match"
SkipTheRest:
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou @Tyeler just to mention as you said size of the sheet1 woud be around 15 to 20 k rows with 12 columns and in sheet 2 there could be 2k to 3- k rows.  

Will be trying your code shortly and surely get back with update :)

Comment: Your code seems to be working but there seems to be little definition error as when I an the same it says For each control on array must be variant so I changed the "sheet2Val As String" to "sheet2Val As Variant" then ran then it said (error) "Script out of range"  Please help

Comment: please see I have mentioned the steps I performed.

Comment: its working but the only problem is its copying all the rows from sheet 1 to sheet3

Comment: I fixed the code. That's what I get for not testing it before posting it as an answer... I also added some quality of life features.